# RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown

Tags: python, windows, telegram, apscheduler

I'm programming a python robot in the telegram, but I have an error that is not resolved, the error is in the schedule

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vini6\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 979, in _process_jobs
    executor.submit_job(job, run_times)
  File "C:\Users\vini6\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 71, in submit_job
    self._do_submit_job(job, run_times)
  File "C:\Users\vini6\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\pool.py", line 28, in _do_submit_job
    f = self._pool.submit(run_job, job, job._jobstore_alias, run_times, self._logger.name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 169, in submit
    raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after '
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown
```

Comment: Are you using python-telegram-bot?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419800/error-cannot-schedule-new-futures-after-interpreter-shutdown-with-boto3-while

Answer (score 11):

In case you are using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), you might be missing an `updater.idle()` call  after `updater.start_polling()`

I reported a bug [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2863), and got this solution as a reply, which fixed it for me. I had the very same error message, although it is a different package here. So leaving this for folks that come here, after searching for the above error message.

Comment: What about pyrogram?

Answer (score 9):

It's bug or something of python 3.9.9. I also came across this issue. But it works well on python 3.7 and python 3.8. Not sure if any other python3.9.x works

Update on 2022/02/11, this issue exists from python3.9 to python 3.10

Comment: Interesting, I am also encountering same exception on python 3.9

Comment: @anarchist912 But I am not using python-telegram-bot. If it is not a bug, then python clearly modified some low-level stuffs so the original method doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @anarchist912, I am also not using python-telegram-bot. But I am using python "schedule" package in conjunction with "asyncio". It does look like a bug with asyncio: https://ittutorialpoint.com/runtimeerror-cannot-schedule-new-futures-after-interpreter-shutdown/

Comment: same here... python 3.9

Comment: Same here with python 3.10

Comment: Anyone still face the same problems ? did apschduler solved it

Answer (score 3):

You may face this issue if your code ends without a blocking loop.
For instance, inside you main.py:

```
# code start
my_function_submitting_tasks_without_waiting()
# end of file
```

Instead you can do something like that

```
# code start
my_function_submitting_tasks_without_waiting()
while True:
  pass
# end of file
```

But of course instead of "while True", you could use a "while not self._signal_stop:" inside your main class

Answer (score 1):

Well, i have faced the same issue as of 28-Jun-2022 and landed here while searching.
After some trial and error i have found some work around which works for me as of now.

### Solution 1 (trick)

What we need is to stop the program to exit. So adding some pause at the end worked for me. Here the example is with *BackgroundScheduler* but any Non-blocking Scheduler will have same approach.

```
import pause
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# your code goes here

# start scheduler
scheduler.start()

# add pause in main
pause.days(1) # or it can anything as per your need
```

### Solution 2

Use *BlockingScheduler* instead of *BackgroundScheduler*

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

# your code goes here

scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Solution 2 works for me. I check python version in the script and import relative scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem while shutting down the scheduler, `.shutdown(wait=False)` worked fine.

```py
c = 0
def tick():
    global c
    print(c)
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' %
          datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    # sleep(5)
    print('After sleep! The time is: %s' %
          datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    c += 1
    if c == 3:
        # sched.remove_job('my_job_id')
        sched.shutdown(wait=False)


def main():
    sched.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=1,
                  next_run_time=datetime.now(),  # start immediately
                  id='my_job_id')
    sched.print_jobs()
    sched.start()
```