# Generating an async effect in a flask app; does joining a thread to the parent process block the process

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, process

One of my `flask` endpoints, I create a process to run a "long job" before sending the user-agent a "ticket".  The user-agent uses that ticket to "check-in"... and retrieve the results when ready.

The following takes place in the process:

1. generate the "long job" result (can involve consuming 0 or more additional threads; joined when multiple threads are required to complete the job)
2. once (1) is complete, write that result to a place where the user-agent "knows" to get it
3. kick-off a "fire and forget" background task that copies files to a shared cache resource; using current_app resources

Before including the following in the body of the function used to instantiate the process:

```
thread_handle.join()
```

([per the lucid explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419800/error-cannot-schedule-new-futures-after-interpreter-shutdown-while-working-thr))

I would get

```
cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown;
```

### The question

Since writing out this question, the answer seems more clear to me.  Notwithstanding,is it ever possible to generate a "computing task" in the flask request context, that captures the "fire and forget" intent; i.e., one where the task will execute and shutdown without the parent process or thread needing to remain in memory? ... do all resources (e.g., access to os resources) depend on the parent process?

If so, that seems a bit inconsistent with what I have intuited given how the life of a process does not depend on the success/failure of the child thread.

Furthermore, if it blocks the process, what's the point of creating a new Thread?  Given that the "fire and forget" thread is the last step in the "long job" and only requires a single thread (no parallel processing), I'm thinking that spawning a new thread is a wasted effort; I should just run it in the process. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, calling .join() on a thread wait till that thread exists and blocks the parent thread until that has happened

you should just run it in the process directly